# Add return key or Done button to `phonePad` keyboard type of TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, normal keyboards come with return key which can be used to dismiss the keyboard. However, for specific keyboard types like `phonePad` there is no return key.

There are few hacks using which we can add accessory view, but, is there any SwiftUI way of handling this?

Here is my code

```
TextField("Phone Number", text: .constant("12345"))
                    .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                    .textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've used is an `onTapGesture()` on the container of my app. You can set the focused state of the input to false on a tap outside of the keyboard like so:

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @FocusState private var focusItem: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", value: $someValue, format: .number)
                .onSubmit {focusItem = false}
                .keyboardType(.number)
                .focused($focusItem)
        }.onTapGesture{
            focusItem = false
        }
    }
}
```

simply tap the screen to drop the keyboard (note this is for .number type keyboard but I expect it to work the same)

Comment: iso 15 only/....

Comment: Thank you! After installing libraries for this and not being able to use them, this is a simple trick to make it work. Shame it doesn't work by default.

Comment: It does mean however buttons cannot be pressed

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way but IMO the best option is to add a toolbar as shown [here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-pure-swiftui-keyboard-toolbar-16a3d092b4df):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var phoneNumber = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            KeyboardView {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Phone Number", text: $phoneNumber)
                        .padding()
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 1)
                        .frame(height: 50))
                        .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                    Spacer()
                }
            } toolBar: {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    } label: { Text("Done") }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

```
class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    private var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter
    @Published private(set) var height: CGFloat = .zero
    init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
        notificationCenter = center
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
    func dismiss() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
    deinit { notificationCenter.removeObserver(self) }
    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        height = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height ?? .zero
    }
    @objc func keyBoardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        height = .zero
    }
}
```

---

```
struct KeyboardView<Content, ToolBar>: View where Content: View, ToolBar: View {
    @StateObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()
    let toolbarFrame = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40)
    var content: () -> Content
    var toolBar: () -> ToolBar
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content().padding(.bottom, keyboard.height == .zero ? .zero : toolbarFrame.height)
            VStack {
                 Spacer()
                 toolBar()
                    .frame(width: toolbarFrame.width, height: toolbarFrame.height)
                    .background(Color.secondary)
            }
            .opacity(keyboard.height == .zero ? .zero : 1)
            .animation(.easeOut)
        }
        .padding(.bottom, keyboard.height)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .animation(.easeOut)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve this with an **iOS Version < 15** and couldn't use *@FocusState*.

I solved this by placing the keyboard toolbar at the bottom of a `VStack` and only displaying it when the keyboard appears. The keyboard pushes the toolbar on top of it.

To accomplish this you need code that publishes changes of when the keyboard appears/disappears. I used an extension on `View` to be notified of these published changes:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

extension View {
var keyboardPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    Publishers
        .Merge(
            NotificationCenter
                .default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                .map { _ in true },
            NotificationCenter
                .default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
                .map { _ in false })
        .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}}
```

Now we can use the `onReceive` closure on our View to set our `keyboardIsPresented` @State property. `keyboardIsPresented` determines if we show/hide keyboard toolbar. See code below for implementation:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {

@State var keyboardIsPresented: Bool = false
@State var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Keyboard Toolbar Test", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding()
        Spacer()
        
        // If keyboard is Presented
        if keyboardIsPresented {
            // Display Toolbar View
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    // Dismiss keyboard
                    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(
                        #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),
                        to: nil,
                        from: nil,
                        for: nil
                    )
                } label: {
                        Text("Done")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .padding(.trailing)
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40)
            .background(Color.indigo)
        }
    }.onReceive(keyboardPublisher) { presented in
        self.keyboardIsPresented = presented
    }
}}
```

This is what my View looks like with the keyboard and toolbar:

[image: Keyboard shown with toolbar]

Hope this helps!